# Divide a column value into multiple rows by number of months based on start date & end date columns

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, scala-spark

I want to divide the quantity value into multiple rows divided by number of months from start date & end date column. Each row should have start date and end date of the month. I also want remaining quantity based on previous value. Below is my sample input and output.

[image: Sample input& output]

Comment: When possible, it's preferably to share code, data, etc.. in textual format. Avoid using images unless is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Split column value into multiple rows  using SQL

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

DECLARE @dateranges TABLE( BegDate DATE, EndDate DATE,Qty int)

INSERT INTO @dateranges( BegDate, EndDate,qty)
VALUES( '01-01-2023',   '31-05-2023', 2000)

;WITH CTE AS    
(

    --initial part

    SELECT  BegDate AS StartOfMonth, DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(MM, 1, BegDate)) AS EndOfMonth, EndDate,qty/datediff(month,begdate,dateadd(month,1,enddate)) as quantity, qty - qty/datediff(month,begdate,dateadd(month,1,enddate)) as rem_quantity
    FROM @dateranges

    -- recursive part
    UNION ALL

    SELECT  DATEADD(MM, 1, StartOfMonth) AS StartOfMonth,  
        DATEADD(DD, -1, DATEADD(MM, 2, StartOfMonth)) AS EndOfMonth,  
        EndDate, Quantity, Rem_quantity - Quantity as Rem_quantity  
    FROM CTE  
    WHERE DATEADD(MM, 1, StartOfMonth)< EndDate  
)
SELECT  StartOfMonth, EndOfMonth, Quantity, rem_quantity
FROM CTE
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/unreadablecode/

Answer (score 0):

based on what I understood from the input and output in question, here's an example

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('seq', 
               func.expr('sequence(trunc(start, "month"), last_day(end), interval 1 month)')
               ). \
    withColumn('seq_st_end', 
               func.transform('seq', 
                              lambda x, i: func.struct(x.alias('start'), 
                                                       func.last_day(x).alias('end'), 
                                                       (func.col('qty')/func.size('seq')).alias('qty'),
                                                       (func.col('qty') - ((func.col('qty')/func.size('seq')) * (i+1))).alias('remaining_qty')
                                                       )
                              )
               ). \
    selectExpr('inline(seq_st_end)'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------+----------+-----+-------------+
# |start     |end       |qty  |remaining_qty|
# +----------+----------+-----+-------------+
# |2023-01-01|2023-01-31|400.0|1600.0       |
# |2023-02-01|2023-02-28|400.0|1200.0       |
# |2023-03-01|2023-03-31|400.0|800.0        |
# |2023-04-01|2023-04-30|400.0|400.0        |
# |2023-05-01|2023-05-31|400.0|0.0          |
# +----------+----------+-----+-------------+
```

we can use `sequence` to create an array of month-dates within the start & end. using the array, we can `transform` it to calculate the start & end dates for each month, and the quantity columns.